# Program hangs when vertical scrollbar appears in databound datagridview after adding rows to datasource via

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, scrollbar, freeze

Repost since I didn't ask the question correctly.
Written in VB.NET 4.6 is my POS Scan project.
Its designed to handle scans from a scanner through a com port.
when scanning something, the event handler (subSerialDataHandler) calls subHandleScan which will decide what to do with the scan based on case.
the scans will be displayed in dgBarcodes. 
You can also manually add an item to the dgBarcodes's datasource (dtBarcodes) via a btnManuallyAdd, that will call the same subHandleScan.

Now here's the bit i'm struggeling with;
when scanning enough items so that a scrollbar needs to appear in the datagridview, the program hangs.
when manually adding items through the button, the program doesn't hang, even if the scrollbar needs to appear. 
Scanning few enough items so that the scrollbar doesn't need to appear, the program doesn't hang.
What could cause this, and what do I need to do to prevent the program from hanging?

Here's the code

```
     Imports System.IO.Ports
     Imports System.Configuration
     Imports System.Threading
    Imports System.Threading.Tasks
     Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
     Imports Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core
     Imports POS_Scan.clsUtilities
     
     Public Class frmPractice
         Public Shared frmRefund As New frmRefund 'create an instance of the form
         Public Shared frmExchangeIn As New frmExchangeIn 'create an instance of the form
         Public Shared frmExchangeOut As New frmExchangeOut 'create an instance of the form
         Public Delegate Sub dlgRefund(strBarcode As String) 'Delegates for other form access
         Public Delegate Sub dlgExchangeIn(strBarcode As String) 'Delegates for other form access
         Public Delegate Sub dlgExchangeOut(strBarcode As String) 'Delegates for other form access
         Dim mySerialPort() As SerialPort
         Dim dtBarcodes As New DataTable
         Public Shared strAction As String = "Sale" 'Semaphore to dictate how to process a barcode scan event.
     
         Private Sub frmPractice_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
             dtBarcodes.Columns.Add("dScan", Type.GetType("System.String")) 'create a column with a string input
             dtBarcodes.Columns.Add("strBarcode", Type.GetType("System.String")) 'create a column with a string input
             dtBarcodes.Columns.Add("strMethod", Type.GetType("System.String")) 'create a column with a string input
             dtBarcodes.Columns.Add("strAmount", Type.GetType("System.String")) 'create a column with a string input
     
             subSerialListener()
     
             dgBarcodes.DataSource = dtBarcodes.DefaultView 'bind it
         End Sub
     
         Private Sub subSerialListener()
             Dim strPorts() As String
             strPorts = fnGetSerialPorts() 'get all serial ports of this computer
     
             Dim intNumberOfPorts As Integer = strPorts.Count - 1
             ReDim mySerialPort(intNumberOfPorts) 'create a 0 based array of serial ports with the right size
             For i = 0 To intNumberOfPorts
                 mySerialPort(i) = New SerialPort(strPorts(i))
                 mySerialPort(i).BaudRate = 9600
                 mySerialPort(i).Parity = Parity.None
                 mySerialPort(i).StopBits = StopBits.One
                 mySerialPort(i).DataBits = 8
                 mySerialPort(i).Handshake = Handshake.None
                 mySerialPort(i).RtsEnable = True
     
                 AddHandler mySerialPort(i).DataReceived, AddressOf subSerialDataHandler
                 mySerialPort(i).Open()
                 'mySerialPort(i).Close()
             Next i
         End Sub
     
         Private Function fnGetSerialPorts() As String()
             Dim strPorts As String() = SerialPort.GetPortNames() 'get an array of port names of this computer
             Return strPorts
         End Function
     
         Private Sub subSerialDataHandler(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)
             Dim sp As SerialPort = CType(sender, SerialPort) 'convert the sender into a serialport
             Dim strInData As String = sp.ReadExisting() 'take the data in the serialport and put it in a string
             subHandleScan(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.ff"), strInData, "Scan") 'pass it to the scan
         End Sub
     
         Private Sub subHandleScan(strDScan As String, strBarcode As String, strMethod As String)
             Dim strNow As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
             Select Case strAction
                 Case "Sale" 'if the scan was a sale
                     subWriteDebugLog(strNow, strMethod, strBarcode) 'write debuglog for a Sale scan
                     Dim row1 As DataRow = dtBarcodes.NewRow() 'make a new row
                     row1("dScan") = strDScan 'set the date
                     row1("strBarcode") = strBarcode 'set the barcode
                     row1("strMethod") = strMethod 'set the method
                     dtBarcodes.Rows.Add(row1) 'add the row
     
                 Case "Refund" 'if the scan was a refund 
                     subWriteDebugLog(strNow, "RefundScan", strBarcode) 'write debuglog for a Refund scan
                     If frmRefund.txtReturnedBarcode.InvokeRequired Then 'Calling from another thread
                         Dim dlgRefund As New dlgRefund(AddressOf frmRefund.subScan) 'sets frmRefund.txtReturnedBarcode.Text =
 strBarcode
                         Me.Invoke(dlgRefund, strBarcode) 'Execute delegate in the UI thread, pass args as an array
                     End If
     
                 Case "ExchangeIn"
                     subWriteDebugLog(strNow, "ExchangeInScan", strBarcode) 'write debuglog for a ExchangeIn scan
                     If frmExchangeIn.txtReturnedBarcode.InvokeRequired Then 'Calling from another thread 
                         Dim dlgExchangeIn As New dlgExchangeIn(AddressOf frmExchangeIn.subScan) 'sets
 frmExchangeIn.txtReturnedBarcode.Text = strBarcode
                         Me.Invoke(dlgExchangeIn, strBarcode) 'Execute delegate in the UI thread, pass args as an array
                     End If
     
                 Case "ExchangeOut"
                     subWriteDebugLog(strNow, "ExchangeOutScan", strBarcode) 'write debuglog for a ExchangeOut scan
                     If frmExchangeOut.txtExchangedBarcode.InvokeRequired Then 'Calling from
 another thread
                         Dim dlgExhangeOut As New dlgExchangeOut(AddressOf frmExchangeOut.subScan) 'sets
 frmExchangeOut.txtExchangedBarcode.Text = strBarcode 
                         Me.Invoke(dlgExhangeOut, strBarcode) 'Execute delegate in the UI thread, pass args as an array
                     End If
             End Select
         End Sub
     
         Private Sub btnManuallyAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnManuallyAdd.Click
             Dim strBarcode As String = Trim(txtManualBarcode.Text)
             If strBarcode <> "" Then 'if the clean string pulled from the textbox isn't empty
                 Dim dateTrans As DateTime = Now
                 subHandleScan(dateTrans.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.ff"), strBarcode, "Manual") 'handle the scan
                 subWriteDebugLog(dateTrans.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"), "btnManuallyAdd", strBarcode) 'write to the debug log
                 Me.txtManualBarcode.Text = "" 'clear the textbox
             End If
         End Sub



Private Sub btnExchange_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExchange.Click
        frmExchangeIn.frmExchangeOut = frmExchangeOut 'pass the instance to the child
        strAction = "ExchangeIn" 'set the mode
        subWriteDebugLog(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"), "btnExchange", "")  'write to the debug log
        frmExchangeIn.txtReturnedBarcode.Text = "" 'clear the control
        frmExchangeIn.ShowDialog(Me) 'show it
        If frmExchangeIn.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then 'if the child form saved something
            Dim strReturnedBarcode As String = frmExchangeIn.strReturnedBarcode 'get the barcode
            Dim strExchangedBarcode As String = frmExchangeIn.strExchangedBarcode 'get the barcode
            Dim row1 As DataRow = dtBarcodes.NewRow() 'make a new row
            Dim row2 As DataRow = dtBarcodes.NewRow() 'make a new row
            Dim dateNow As DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.ff") 'grab the time so its the exact same for both rows
            'new item
            row1("dScan") = dateNow 'set the date
            row1("strBarcode") = strExchangedBarcode 'set the barcode
            row1("strMethod") = "-Exchange" 'set the method
            'Returned item
            row2("dScan") = dateNow 'set the date
            row2("strBarcode") = strReturnedBarcode 'set the barcode
            row2("strMethod") = "+Exchange" 'set the method
            dtBarcodes.Rows.Add(row1) 'add the row
            dtBarcodes.Rows.Add(row2) 'add the row
        End If
        strAction = "Sale" 'reset the mode
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnRefund_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRefund.Click
        strAction = "Refund" 'set the mode
        subWriteDebugLog(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"), "btnRefund", "")  'write to the debug log

        frmRefund.txtDate.Text = "" 'clear the control
        frmRefund.txtTime.Text = "" 'clear the control
        frmRefund.txtTotalValue.Text = "" 'clear the control
        frmRefund.txtReturnedBarcode.Text = "" 'clear the control
        frmRefund.txtReturnedValue.Text = "" 'clear the control
        frmRefund.ShowDialog(Me) 'show it
        If frmRefund.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then 'if the child form saved something
            Dim strReturnedBarcode As String = frmRefund.strReturnedBarcode 'get the barcode
            Dim decValue As Decimal = frmRefund.decValue 'get the value
            Dim row As DataRow = dtBarcodes.NewRow() 'make a new row
            row("dScan") = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.ff") 'set the date
            row("strBarcode") = strReturnedBarcode 'set the barcode
            row("strMethod") = "Refund" 'set the method
            row("strAmount") = "-" & CStr(decValue) 'set the amount
            dtBarcodes.Rows.Add(row) 'add the row
        End If
        strAction = "Sale" 'reset the mode
    End Sub
```

Comment: Please, paste code without all those `>` symbols. -- You should also remove all those shared objects, e.g., `Public Shared frmRefund As New frmRefund()`. It's also not clear when these Forms are shown. -- I think you've already asked this question; IIRC, the problems are still the same. The `InvokeRequired` / `Invoke()` pattern is not implemented correctly (IIRC, as before). You're most probably trying to handle existing instances of already shown Forms (possibly default instances) using unrelated static instances.

Comment: Hi Jimi, yes this is the same question, but I got the feeling that the first post wasn't exactly clear what my problem is and fix I need. forms are shown when their respective button click event handler is triggered. But the event handler's themselves aren't relevant for the issue (I think). I decided to include the form declarations at the top of the class because in the last post I was queried whether I was working on the default instance or not. this should show that I'm not.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still unclear what you're doing there. You have those static (`Shared`) instances of Forms that you never seem to show at any point: what comes to mind is that you're trying to use these instances to access methods / properties and, much worse, Controls of existing Forms of the same Type that are already shown. -- Remove all those static instances to begin with (this is not the way to handle Forms anyway) and post the code that shows the real instances of the Forms that contain the Controls you're trying to update.

Comment: @jimi I've added the event handlers for the button's that open the child forms to the post above now, hopefully that clears it up. If I remove the static instances at the top of the class, what do I do then to get the same functionality? Thank you for your help!